# How to get recycler view current item text value in activity in VIEW BINDING

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am having a recycler view and I need to get the value of the current item of recyclerView which consists of text views and other views. before view binding, it is pretty straight forward as follows :

```
recyclerview.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i)!!.itemView.mDescription.text.toString()
```

now after enabling view binding in the recyclerView adapter, I am not able to get access the editTextDescription from activity.
Any help is appreciated.

Here is my adapter which contains textView, editText, checkbox, etc. What I want is that on the click of a button from Activity it should get data from recyclerView adapter (ListAdapter) of the item at a particular position and submit it to the REST api.

```
class SpiranAdapter(private val list: List<Spiran>)
    : RecyclerView.Adapter<SpiranViewHolder>() {
   override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: SpiranViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val spiran: Spiran = list[position]
        holder.bind(spiran)
    }
}
class SpiranViewHolder(inflater: LayoutInflater, parent: ViewGroup) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false)) {
    private var mTitleView: TextView? = null

    init {
        mTitleView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_title) // textView
        mYearView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_description) //textView
        mDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.description) // as EditText
        isServiceOpted = itemView.findViewById(R.id.isServiceOpted) // checkbox
    }
    fun bind(spiran: Spiran) {
        mTitleView?.text = spiran.title
        mYearView?.text = spiran.year.toString()
        mDescription?.setText(spiran.description);
        isServiceOpted as Checkable).isChecked = spiran.status
    }

}
```

*There is no any click listener apart from checkbox. There is editText and I need value from that editText to activity*

Comment: Please share the RecyclerView Adapter code where you have enabled View Binding.

Comment: you want to add on click listener on your recycler view? I mean on click list item you want to fetch the value?

Comment: @VarshaKulkarni I want to get the visible item value without interfering with the adapter, and that's why I don't need click listener over there.

Comment: More code would definitely help understand what exactly is the issue you are facing with view binding.

Comment: When used with ViewBinding you can just use this way right? `binding.recyclerview.findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(i)!!.itemView.mDescription.text.toString()` Are you facing any issue with this?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should user interface here.